# How to upgrade latest linux kernel offline.

Tags: upgrade, kernel

How to upgrade linux [kernel](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.16.tar.xz) offline in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Is that a claim or a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download kernel packages to upgrade. If you already have kernel .deb packages you do not have to be online.

If you want to upgrade kernel of Ubuntu you can use my script. It always will be up to date.

[ukupgrade: Ubuntu Kernel Upgrade](https://github.com/muhasturk/ukupgrade)